# How should freelancers apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen-visas, freelance

My friend and I are planning a Euro trip this October. Our port of entry is Frankfurt and will be going to Reykjavik (Iceland), Berlin, Prague, Vienna, Munich and back to Frankfurt.

We live in Mumbai, India and will be applying to the German Consulate here in Mumbai.

We both are freelancers. I am a freelancing software engineer and he is a freelancing business development manager. We do not have any company or corporation under which we freelance.

I went through their site to find out the documents needed but wanted to ask people here if being a freelancer will cause any issues for our visa application? Anything else we would need to submit to make our case strong?

Comment: It *will* be an issue. They like to see people with an incentive to return home after the visit, and being employed with a good job is just about the best case. But of course a visa will still be possible. It would be good if you had a steady and predictable income. An established business practice with customers in India will help as well. They want to say/see "well, he'd be stupid to give all that up and become an illegal immigrant."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is going to be difficult for me to show as my customers are US based. Any idea what can be done in such situation?

Comment: You can provide screen shots of transactions  , projects and all supporting evidences . All of these documents although in digital form or pictures will help them understand your status . Meanwhile you may try to get a local client which may show that you've to come back for your responsibilities.